# How to get book cover from ISBN using Google Book API?

Tags: google-books

Is there a simple way to get book cover in JSON format from ISBN using Google Book API?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the `isbn:` query, like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0771595158
```

This will return a proper JSON response containing either the book information or an error description if the ISBN is not found.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Simple enough ;)

Comment: @Chan No problem. Just a bit of googling :)

Comment: It should be noted that you should not assume that when the JSON response contains the book information, `volumeInfo.imageLinks` will *always* be present. This is not the case.

Comment: When I search your link, returns me:

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "unknownLocation",
    "message": "Cannot determine user location for geographically restricted operation."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Cannot determine user location for geographically restricted operation."
 }
}

Comment: The link in the answer is currently not providing a meaningful response. Here's one which does, with book cover images: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781461492986

Comment: It seems all ISBN requests returns the following response: `{"kind": "books#volumes", "totalItems": 0}`

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko what ISBN did you try? https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9781447929536 also works

Comment: @edonbajrami see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927398/google-books-api-cannot-determine-user-location-for-geographically-restricted

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an answer for a Ruby (Rails, Sinatra or Console) answer on how to get a conver image or for that matter any detail available through the Google Books API, I think [GoogleBooks](https://github.com/zeantsoi/GoogleBooks) gem is a good place to start.

For example, for the same scenario:

Install the gem

```
gem install googlebooks
```

Use the gem

```
require 'googlebooks'
GoogleBooks.search('isbn:9781443411080').first.image_link
```

`first` because it returns a collection of books.