# Google Books API: "Cannot determine user location for geographically restricted operation."

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-books

Since three days I get the above mentioned error message when trying to access google books api, although my IP didn't change. I can reproduce that on the command line with a simple

`curl "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=frankenstein"`

So it's not my code. It can be fixed adding a country code:

`curl "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=frankenstein&country=DE"`

Now how do I do that in the PHP client?

I tried adding country as an optional Parameter:

```php
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My_Project");
$client->setDeveloperKey( $google_books_api_key );
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$optParams = array(
    'country' => 'DE'
);
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes($terms, $optParams);
```

but that just gives me

`{"error": {"errors": [{"domain": "global","reason": "backendFailed","message": "Service temporarily unavailable.","locationType": other","location": "backend_flow"}],"code": 503,"message": "Service emporarily anavailable."}}`

A solution I found somwhere to set the users IP to one I do have access from still gave me the 'geographically restricted' error message.

```php
$optParams = array(
    'userIp' => '91.64.137.131'
);
```

I found solutions for clients other then PHP like [Java?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/books-api/zYETdaACrnU;context-place=topicsearchin/books-api/Cannot$20determine$20user$20location$20for$20geographically$20restricted$20operation) or [Ruby](https://github.com/zeantsoi/GoogleBooks/commit/c8ff23cb7da1474089e6a4e9e97d517c6517cde8) or [C#](http://otomatikmuhendis.com/2016/10/15/google-book-api-geographically-restricted-operation-error/) but they didn't seem helpful to me.

In the PHP client a *setCountry($country)* method exists in 'class Google_Service_Books_VolumeAccessInfo extends Google_Model' but I don't know how to access that method. Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: A solution was posted on https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1595#issuecomment-468291083

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in titles here. You can either answer your question and accept it or delete the question

Comment: While I do understand the reasons it would feel weird to present the solution as mine or delete the questions since it was asked so many times in different places. I will ask the person who solved it if he posts here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this in a manner similar to the other language examples you shared by using middlewares:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler;

// Set this value to the country you want.
$countryCode = 'DE';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My_Project");
$client->setDeveloperKey( $google_books_api_key );
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$optParams = [];

$handler = new CurlHandler;
$stack = HandlerStack::create($handler);
$stack->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function ($request) use ($countryCode) {
    $request = $request->withUri(Uri::withQueryValue(
        $request->getUri(),
        'country',
        $countryCode
    ));

    return $request;
}));
$guzzle = new Client([
    'handler' => $stack
]);

$client->setHttpClient($guzzle);

$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes($terms, $optParams);
```

Middleware is a set of functions which are used to modify requests and responses. This example adds a request middleware, which prior to dispatching the request, will add `country=$countryCode` to the URI query string.

This example is simplified to some extent, and you'll need to work on it a bit. The big issue is that this middleware will add the country code to *every* request sent from this instance of `Google_Client`. I suggest adding additional logic to limit the modification to this request only.