# How to retrieve an url to a book cover only knowing its isbn

Tags: html, cover, isbn, domo, google-books-api

is there a way to obtain an URL to a cover of a book when only knowing the book's API?

I have tried two approaches yet.
First, https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/covers which does not work for me since they did not find any covers for the relatively new german books that I need the cover links for

Then I tried the google books API https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using which was more promising. It is possible to search via ISBN there and the Google API found data for the books I'm interested in.

Unfortunately, the google API returns a JSON object. This JSON object contains a link to the book's cover. However, I cannot use Javascript/php or something in my application to retrieve the cover URL from the JSON object.

I can only use HTML and therefore need a direct link to a cover when providing a book ISBN instead of a JSON object containing the URL.

Ideally, a cover URL for a book with ISBN XXX would look like this
https://some_text/XXX/some_text such that I can directly use it as src in an HTML image container.

Does anyone have an idea on how to approach this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*I cannot use Javascript/php or something in my application*" How are you implementing this API integration without a higher-level language, exactly?

Comment: I am not really integrating the API, I just followed [the answer provided in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422528/how-to-get-book-cover-from-isbn-using-google-book-api) and used an ISBN query. But since it does not return the URL string as [openlibrary](https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/covers) does I cannot use the information in the JSON object due to the lack of a higher-language

Comment: I use [DOMO](https://www.domo.com/de) to visualize data and created a bestseller list for books. I want to add the books cover as a column in the table their now, but DOMO does only support basic HTML [(see here)](https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043430033-Adding-Graphics-Links-and-Images-to-Table-Cards-Using-Beast-Mode)

I cannot hardcode the cover link since the table shows bestsellers of the last week and the data that populate the table are constantly chaning

Comment: Are you sure about all this...? Can you cite a source upon which you're basing your claims regarding DOMO's featureset limiting support to only "*basic HTML*"? A cursory search turned up resources around [writing custom JavaScript to build a custom connector](https://developer.domo.com/docs/custom-connectors/connector-dev-studio) which it seems is exactly what you're after, or alternatively using one of DOMO's various pre-existing JSON connectors to get the job done. Why does that not meet your requirements?

Comment: No, I am definitely not sure about all of this. I describe things as I understand them at the moment but maybe I misunderstood some of them.

I did not look that much into connectors yet because I thought they are used to connect data sources to domo. In my case, I already have Data in my Domo Instance (Book title/Book author/Book ISBN/ Book sales). The dataset has multiple millions of rows and I do not want to append these data with a cover_link row but just dynamically load and display the covers of the top books shown in my table.

Comment: I will look into Connectors though, as I said, I might just not understand their concept/use cases correctly. Do you think I can use COnnectors for the use case described above? Thank you very much for taking your time to help me out btw.